# bash: trying to put the output of "find" into a variable by using "$()" but it does not work

Tags: bash, find

The purpose of my script is to provide a full path to the last sub-directory, based on the value provided by the user input.
For example, the following script:

```
./script.sh TICKET-1234
```

should output something like this:

```
The full path is --> /share/data/TICKET-1234/some/other/sub/dir
```

I'm trying to implement this with the following code:

```
rootPath="/share/data/"
anchorDir="${1}"
restOfPath=$(find /rootPath/$1/ -type d)
#fullPath=rootPath+anchorDir+restOfPath
echo "rest of path is $restofPath"
```

Currently I only checking whether "`restOfPath`" gets assigned the value that I expect - namely, all the remaining directories that are under `TICKET-1234` dir.  However, I get the following output:

```
./script.sh TICKET-1234
rest of path is /share/data/TICKET-1234/
/share/data/TICKET-1234/client
/share/data/TICKET-1234/client/region
/share/data/TICKET-1234/client/region/logs/
/share/data/TICKET-1234/client/region/logs/2019
```

How could I capture only the second part of last path in the output ("`/client/region/logs/2019`") and assign it to `$restOfPath` variable?

Thank you

Comment: `restOfPath` is NOT the same as `restofPath`: case matters in Unix. Fix your example -- do NOT post pseudocode.

Comment: Fix all other types: show the code that is causing the problem, not something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Error line 3: missing `$` in front of rootPath.

Comment: it should be a typo... if OP really missed in code. he won't be getting the result he shared.

Comment: If OP dose no show the real code, then we can not be expected to guess what the problem is.

Comment: agreed!!!......

Answer (score 0):

First the find command is missing `$` sign. ANd to get only deepest directory you can use find like this:

```
restOfPath=$(find $rootPath/$1 -type d -links 2)
```

You can try also this way (which is a bit odd but will do the work):

```
restOfPath=$(find $rootPath/$1 -type d |awk '{lnew=gsub(/\//,"/",$0); if (lnew > l) {l=lnew p=$0}; } END {print p}')
```

Comment: `-links 2` is not reliable on all filesystems; on btrfs, ALL directories have a link count of 1.

Comment: we don't require / before $rootpath as well...

Comment: @mosvy, i add version w/o `-links`, with ugly `awk` code :)

Answer (score 0):

Result of applying the fixes suggested by [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to your script.

```
rootPath="/share/data/"
anchorDir="${1}"
restOfPath=$(find /rootPath/"$1"/ -type d)
#fullPath=rootPath+anchorDir+restOfPath
echo "rest of path is $restOfPath"
```

Before applying changes following issues were detected

```
Line 3:
rootPath="/share/data/"
^-- SC2034: rootPath appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 4:
anchorDir="${1}"
^-- SC2034: anchorDir appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 5:
restOfPath=$(find /rootPath/$1/ -type d)
^-- SC2034: restOfPath appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
restOfPath=$(find /rootPath/"$1"/ -type d)

Line 7:
echo "rest of path is $restofPath"
                      ^-- SC2154: restofPath is referenced but not assigned (did you mean 'restOfPath'?).
```

Comment: you may have `shellcheck` installed. No need to share your code with some web-site. It is a package in Debian.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Unfortunately, I'm working on a machine whose OS is not a Linux :(. Nor do I have the permission to install on it Shellcheck binary version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
find /rootPath/$1/  -type d -printf '/%P\n'
/
/client
/client/region
/client/region/logs
/client/region/logs/2019
```

if we need only the last line ,

```
find /rootPath/$1/  -type d -printf '/%P\n' | tail -n1
/client/region/logs/2019
```

> %P File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

Comment: What if i have paths `/client/region/logs/2019` and `/client/region/l/g/s/19`? Which one is deeper?

Comment: obviously `/client/region/l/g/s/19` is deeper... I'm getting the same result.

Comment: normally you can't rely on the sort of list of `find`. If directory is `/client/region/a/g/s/19` you can get it before `/client/region/logs`